# Python Tensorflow with GPU on Windows 11

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras, gpu

Tensorflow can't find my GPU.

I've read that "TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows" (https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tensorflow-not-detecting-gpu/16295), but I updated it to 2.12.0 without knowing that and now it can't find my GPU.

When I try to install the 2.10.0 version with `pip install tensorflow==2.10.0` it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.10.0 (from versions: 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.13.0rc0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.10.0
```

I tried recreating the venv over and over again and it still does not work.

I tried installing tensorflow-gpu but the package but it is no longer available and gives an error:

```
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Using cached tensorflow-gpu-2.12.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting python_version>"3.7" (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached python_version-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: tensorflow-gpu
  Building wheel for tensorflow-gpu (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\adria\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0z_mm53i\tensorflow-gpu_3820ba0dd6df42a78900dec118bf1d88\setup.py", line 37, in <module>
          raise Exception(TF_REMOVAL_WARNING)
      Exception:

      =========================================================
      The "tensorflow-gpu" package has been removed!

      Please install "tensorflow" instead.

      Other than the name, the two packages have been identical
      since TensorFlow 2.1, or roughly since Sep 2019. For more
      information, see: pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu
      =========================================================


      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tensorflow-gpu
  Running setup.py clean for tensorflow-gpu
Failed to build tensorflow-gpu
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tensorflow-gpu, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have:

- python version 3.11
- cuda version 11.3;
- cuDNN version 8.2.1;
- conda version 23.3.1.

What can I do to use my GPU again in my project with keras? I need this as soon as possible, I am working at my bachelor project.
If I missed any details please feel free to ask me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: TensorFlow 2.10 is only available for python versions 3.7 to 3.10, and you have 3.11. Check that here: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.10.0/

Comment: Thank you so much! I've upgraded python too from 3.10 to 3.11 without knowing this.